# How do I access members of another query LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

In Visual Studio, in the `Program.cs` class, I add `using ConsoleApp2.Service;` and then i get access to the class and members of the class `ClassService.cs`.
How do I do the same in `LINQPad`?

Other word.
**How to make logic:**

- I create a query `Program. linq'.
- I'm creating a query 'ClassService. linq'.
- I write the namespace `ClassService.linq` in query `Program.linq`.
- **Result:**
  i can implement the code in query `Program.linq` :

  ```
   ClassService slsservice = new ClassService();
   slsservice.MyProperty = 32;
   slsservice.Method1();
  ```

---

**Question:**
How do I access members of another query LINQPad?
Is it possible to implement this logic in LINQPad?

---

***Code for LINQPad***
**Program.linq**

```
void Main()
{ 
  ClassService
  slsservice = new ClassService();
  slsservice.MyProperty = 32;
  slsservice.Method1(); 
}
```

**ClassService.linq**

```
public void Main()
{
 
}
 
public class SubMyClass1
{
 private int myVar;
 
 public int MyProperty
 {
  get { return myVar; }
  set { myVar = value; }
 }
 
 public void Method1()
 {
  // ... Arbitrary code ...
 }
 
}
```

---

***Code for Visual Studio***
**Program.cs**

```
using ConsoleApp2.Service;
 
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            ClassService classService = new ClassService();
 
            classService.MyProperty = 32;
            classService.Method1();
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassService.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleApp2.Service
{
    public class ClassService
    {
 
        private int myVar;
 
        public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }
 
 
        public void Method1()
        {
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

---

**Picture**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#load` directive which must be at the top is to achieve that. You can refer to [the page](https://www.linqpad.net/LinqReference.aspx). I have made a tad presentation as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I prefer this to using MyExtensions , which does not work well when sharing code or moving to another machine.